# How to create a new Firefox profile in Linux or Solaris?

Tags: linux, firefox, solaris, firefox-profile

I know how to create a new Firefox profile in Windows. 
I want to create a new Firefox profile in Linux / Solaris.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

```
firefox -no-remote -ProfileManager
```

Comment: That's the answer I want. It really works!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options), you can either use `firefox -CreateProfile "profile_name profile_dir"` or `firefox -CreateProfile profile_name` based on your need.